# Different content of &a

Tags: c++, reference

Im looking for a better understanding of the following 3 examples.

This is my questions to the following code examples.

- Ex. 1. Example makes sense, it outputs the adress of which the int a
  is stored.
- Ex. 2. Makes a little less sense for. I think it is
  because the char itself points to the char?
- Ex. 3. Confuses me. In
  the output the first char output is always the on stored in the char.
  But what are the appending chars and why do they appear after saving
  &a to a char pointer?

Lastly how do i output the adress of the memory location of where a char variable is saved?

*Ex. 1*

```
main(void) 
{
  int a = 1;
  cout << &a;
}
```

Outputs the memory adress ex. **0x7fff4241b7b4**

*Ex 2.*

```
main(void) 
{
  char a = 'a';
  cout << &a;
}
```

Outputs the char a. ex. **a**

*Ex. 3.*

```
main(void) 
{
  char a = 'a';
  char *b = &a;
  cout << &a;
}
```

Outputs **a��:��**

Comment: The second and third are undefined behaviour. `operator<<` has an overload for `const char *` because of strings.

Comment: This is more to do with the overloads of `std::ostream& operator<<` than the behaviour of `&`.

Comment: @chris: Why would the third output be undefined behavior? It seem perfectly well defined: there is nothing wrong with assigning the address of a `char` to a pointer and taking the address of said pointer. That said, I doubt the output of the third program is what it claimed, it is probably more along the lines of `0x7fff5f174a68`.

Comment: Example 3 prints a hexadecimal memory address for me.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, Oops, my bad. My mind played a dirty trick and said `&b` was a `char *` after seeing the output the OP got.

Comment: I had an error in ex. 3. It was not meant to be &b but &a. Which is the primary reason why im confused. As setting *b to &a is altering the cout of &b

Comment: @AnttiHaapala .. already done that.

Comment: @DietmarKühl wouldn't passing a `char*` which is not a null terminated string to something that expects one result in UB?

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, of course. But the third example doesn't pass the pointer to the `char` anywhere and rather uses the address of the pointer said `char`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I thought the address of a `char` would yield a `char*` here.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Sure. `b` is of type `char*` pointing to a single `char`. Then `&b` is printed which is of type `char**`, i.e., the `void const*` overload of `operator<<()` is used. The `char*` is never interpreted as a C-string.

Comment: @DietmarKühl OK, maybe the confusion is due to the edit. It is `&a` that is being passed in the 3rd example, whereas it used to be `&b`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, this is correct: the version I commented on was using `&b` in the third example, not `&a`. Sorry, I didn't notice that this part of the article got edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first pointer matches the `operator<<(const void*)` that outputs the pointer value; the second and third match `operator<<(const char*)` that will output a null-terminated string.

char `a` is a value on stack, so it is totally undefined whether the bytes after the first byte are null or not, luckily in the middle case it is followed by a null byte, but in the 3rd case some bytes following are not null bytes and you get broken UTF-8 characters. The fact that you are setting a pointer does not affect the running of the program, but the stack frame is set up differently, and GCC for example emits `movb    $97, -9(%rbp)` assembler opcode to set the byte on stack, putting the char in a non-aligned address. The stack layout on my computer is this (64 bit)

```
| x | x | x | x | x | x | a | b | b | b | b | b | b | b | b |
                                                            ^
                                                           RPB
```

Thus `a` is then on stack directly followed by the b pointer value; the garbage I see when running on my machine comes from this pointer value. In fact if I change the ex 3 into

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) 
{
    char a = 'a';
    long b = 0x68676665646362l;
    std::cout << &a;
}
```

I get output

```
abcdefgh
```

Of course this is an example of **undefined behaviour**; compile using another compiler, run on another platform and the program can according to standards as well crash, print the complete text of Hamlet or achieve self-awareness.

Answer (score 2):

The second and third examples outputs the pointer *as a string*. But as the actual data is only a single character with no string terminator, you get undefined behavior as the output operator continues to output beyond the actual data in its search for the terminator.

If you want to print the actual pointer, then you have to cast the pointer:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&a) << '\n';
```

Comment: I would `static_cast`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks this makes sense. I had an error in ex. 3. Could you take a look at this again? Im confused as why setting *b = &a; changes the cout of &a

Comment: @QuackQuacker After your edit, both the second a third examples are equivalent. Having the `b` variable in between should not differ. If you get different output it's because of the undefined behavior you have.

Comment: @QuackQuacker what happens is that you have undefined behaviour. In the 3rd example, creating `b` on the stack seems to put some values after `a` which are not `0`. `cout` expects a nul-terminated string, so...